# How to change the background of an SVG in Codename One

Tags: svg, codenameone

I have an SVG image and I have uploaded it successfully to Codename One and set it as icon to a SpanLabel using setIconMethod. But in the empty parts of the SVG, a black background is shown, and I want the background to be white. I tried to create a UIID with white background and then to use setIconUIID, but it did not work.

How do I set the background for SVG images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codename One doesn't "really" support SVG files. The designer tool allows you to import them but they are saved with fallback images that are PNG's and those are always used.

Native platforms don't work well with SVG's. Android added some support which translates SVG's to drawables on the desktop but that's not "real" SVG support.

Simple single color SVG's can be converted to font icons which are supported.

I would love to have "proper" SVG support but very few people used or expressed interest in this.

Comment: How do I set a transparent background of the fallback image?

Comment: I don't think that's supported. We recommend using multi-images which would deliver roughly the same result in the current implementation.

Comment: @Shai Almog I am trying to import a svg in the theme.res, it has 512px size, I do not know if this is the right size to import, I want that it is translated to multi-image at different dpis but the designer doesn't work. I add svg image from the computer but it is neither saved or translated and the designer GUI seems to be broken. I save the theme but the image is not in the theme.

Comment: I suggest using this for SVG: https://github.com/codenameone/flamingo-svg-transcoder